# How to fix the error in QAP test in SNA: Error in fun(dat, ...) : unused arguments

Tags: r, sna, network-analysis

I would like to compare three networks with the same number of nodes. The three networks G1,G2 & G3 have been created using iGraph, and I have transferred them into network objects, which should be recognizable by SNA. However, when I tried to do a QAP test, I kept coming across the error message: Error in fun(dat, ...) : unused arguments (u2 = 1, u3 = 2). Can anybody help me find the issue? Thanks so much! I'm attaching my code and error message below:

> library(intergraph)
>   library(sna)
>   u1 <- asNetwork(G1)
>   u2 <- asNetwork(G2)
>   u3 <- asNetwork(G3)
>   qaptest(list(u1, u2, u3), gcor, u2 = 1, u3 = 2) 
>   
>   **Error in fun(dat, ...) : unused arguments (u2 = 1, u3 = 2)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK4fW.png)

Comment: You've almost got it--`qaptest(list(u1, u2, u3), gcor, g1 = 1, g2 = 2)` compares the first and second items in your list--so `u1` and `u2`. If you want to compare `u2` and `u3`: `qaptest(list(u1, u2, u3), gcor, g1 = 2, g2 = 3)`. Note that `g1` and `g2` remain the same--those are the argument names.

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem. Thank you so much! @paqmo